# How to add stylesheets by twig template in Symfony

Tags: php, sass, symfony

I followed this tutorial to add sass support in symfony:

https://alexandre.salome.fr/blog/sass-compass-assetic-in-ten-minutes

So far, I have a stylesheets.html.twig with this content:

```
{% stylesheets filter="sass"
    "css/main.scss"
    "css/details.scss"
    "css/talk.scss"
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

that works fine, but how do I add more stylesheets when a specific *.html.twig is used? I guess I cant use blocks when using the filter function like this above.

Answer (score 2):

For Synfony2 it should look like:

```
{% block css %}
    {% stylesheets output='css/compiled/index.css'
        '@MainBundle/Resources/css/editable.css'
    %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

ok dimitrio, your answer directed me to the solution

first problem was, that the stylesheets.html.twig was included, and therefor I couldnt access and overide the block inside it, so I replaced it by use:

```
#base.html.twig
{% use "::stylesheets.html.twig" %}           
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

and inside the stylesheets.html.twig

```
#stylehseets.html.twig
{% block stylesheets %}

    {% stylesheets filter="sass"
        "css/main.scss"
        "css/basic.scss"
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}

{% endblock %}
```

Inside my specific twig I had to add content to the block

```
{% block stylesheets %}

    {{ parent() }}

    {% stylesheets filter="sass"
        "css/specific/show.scss"
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

It works nice, but isn't there a solution that is shorter for the specific twig? Iam looking for something like

```
{% addstylesheet 'css/specific/show.scss' %}
```