# shortcut to add stylesheets to symfony2/twig

Tags: php, css, symfony

A a result of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012793/how-to-add-stylesheets-by-twig-template-in-symfony), I now use this code to add a stylesheet within a twig file:

```
{% block stylesheets %}

    {{ parent() }}

    {% stylesheets filter="sass"
        "test/newstyle.scss"
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

because this code is very unhandy, just to add one more style, I wonder if there is a more shorthand solution? Something like:

```
{% adStylesheet(test/newstyle.scss) %}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible